# How can I use LINQ in C# with a column containing a '-' character?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable in C# and I am attempting to use LINQ to select rows. The issue I am encountering is that a hyphenated column name is being interpreted incorrectly.

Here is the code:

```
DataRow[] matches = myTable.Select("SUB-CATEGORY = '" + sc + "' AND BW = '" + bw + "'");
```

I am getting the error "Cannot find the column [SUB]".

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try using square brackets around the table name, e.g. "[SUB-CATEGORY] = '"...

Comment: This is not LINQ, this is a just a data row filter. [DataRow FIlter Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-6.0#system-data-datatable-select(system-string)). You could use LINQ to filter your rows but you are already mostly there with your filter expression. I would just use it unless you have a need to switch to LINQ. For table fields in general, you want to wrap them in square brackets '[..]' to be sure they are property interpreted.

Comment: You should also use parameters to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: @nullforce While a great suggestion in general, this is a [`DataTable`-specific `Select` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-6.0) and does not actually run a query, so there are no "parameters" to set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments provided, the solution is as follows:

```
DataRow[] matches = myTable.Select("[SUB-CATEGORY] = '" + sc + "' AND BW = '" + bw + "'");
```